# Pylint: Using property decorator's member function results in "no-member" error

Tags: python, pylint

I've run into the following issue with Pylint:

Given the following minimal example:

```
#tpack/__init__.py
class C:
    @property
    def ans(self):
        return 42

def f(c):
    return C.ans.fget(c)
```

Pylint produces the following error:

```
>pylint -d missing-docstring -d invalid-name -d too-few-public-methods tpack
************* Module tpack
tpack\__init__.py:7:11: E1101: Method 'ans' has no 'fget' member (no-member)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.00/10 (previous run: 0.00/10, +0.00)
```

Pylint version:

```
>pylint --version
pylint 2.1.1
astroid 2.0.4
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Is this a known issue with Pylint?

### Edit:

There seems to be some confusion about the use of this piece of code.

Here's an example:

```
>python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tpack import *
>>> c = C()
>>> f(c)
42
```

When accessing a property through the class one acquires the actual property object that the decorator generated. Through this one can access the property object's member functions. `fgets` is the getter. One just has to pass an object of type `C` to it, and the property is returned.

Comment: I don't think so. Properties make no sense in the class context, only in instance context.

Comment: If i recall correctly you hve to set the getters and setters for Properties but i might be wrong

Comment: @E.Serra his property definition is fine, in this case the decorator will attribute a standard getter. The problem is that he is trying to use a property in the context of the class, which makes no sense. This is because properties receive self as an argument, and self is not set for the C class itself, only for instances of C.

Comment: Ye good point didnt noticr he was calling the class

Comment: Please refer to example uses of this code in the question's edit section and in @Mono 's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well all the comments and the answers do make sense in the fact that instance methods should only be called on objects and not on classes. But, here since the method 'ans' is using the @property decorator, calling 'ans' on the class returns a property object.
So, doing

```
print(C.ans)
```

prints

```
<property object at 0x000001A819E55CC8>
```

and

```
c = C()
print(c.ans)
```

prints

```
42
```

So your code is correct. Maybe not Pythonic ideally. But, I have tested your code and it runs just fine.

[image]

So, yeah it's probably an issue with Pylint. I don't have much insights on Pylint. So can't help you there :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Pylint is right here but the message is a bit misleading.

So your `C` class has a property called `ans`, and `ans` definition receives `self` as argument; later you call the `C` class itself with `C.ans` but in the context of the class, what Python is supposed to pass as the `self` argument to `ans`?

So the problem is that `self` is not set in the context of the class, so you can only access properties from an instance of `C`, not from the `C` class itself.